# Display multiple forms when C# application starts

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 3 forms in my C# application -- Form1, Form2 and Form3. Currently when my application starts it loads up Form1. I want all three forms to open on application startup.

I tried doing this in  `Program.cs`:

```
static void Main()
{     
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form1());
    Application.Run(new Form2());
}
```

but Form2 only shows up after Form1 is closed.

How can I make all 3 forms show up simultaneously as soon as the application starts?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Start the other forms from the [`Form.Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load.aspx) event of `Form1`.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 form2 = new Form2();
    form2.Show();
}
```

Comment: The only thing with this is, how does he know when the program is to close?  According to the user, he can close any window at any time.

Comment: @DJBurb Where does he specify the desired close behavior?  Should the application end when *all* 3 are closed, when *any* 3 are closed, or when a particular form is closed?  One, or any, are both easy.  All would be a tad more work.

Comment: I think you need to figure that out yourself, but you can use the [`Form.FormClosing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx) event to find when a form is beeing closed, abort the closing and hide the form instead. When all forms are hidden, close the application.

Comment: @AlbinSunnanbo If you want to wait for all forms to close your best bet would probably to have the main form be a blank hidden form, rather than any one of the regular forms.  have it open all 3 and subscribe to the closing event, and then end when they're all closed.

Comment: @Servy He mentioned it in another reply. I think it was erased

Comment: @DJBurb Yeah, I see that now.

Comment: @Servy - inherit from ApplicationContext; see my answer.

Answer (score 22):

Generally, the right way to have your application do something other than the default (open a form, wait for it to close, then exit) is to make a class that inherits from [`ApplicationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.applicationcontext.aspx). Then you pass an instance of your class to the `Application.Run` method. When the application should close, call `ExitThread()` from within your class.

In this case, you can create instances of the three forms when the application loads, and register a handler for their `Closed` events. When each form is closed, the handler will check if there are any other forms still open, and if not will close the application.

[The example on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.applicationcontext(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_7) is doing two things:

1. opening multiple forms and exiting the application when they are all closed
2. saving the last size and position of the form when each form is closed.

A simpler example, which closes the application only after all the forms are closed:

```
class MyApplicationContext : ApplicationContext {
    private void onFormClosed(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (Application.OpenForms.Count == 0) {
            ExitThread();
        }
    }

    public MyApplicationContext() {
        //If WinForms exposed a global event that fires whenever a new Form is created,
        //we could use that event to register for the form's `FormClosed` event.
        //Without such a global event, we have to register each Form when it is created
        //This means that any forms created outside of the ApplicationContext will not prevent the 
        //application close.

        var forms = new List<Form>() {
            new Form1(),
            new Form2(),
            new Form3()
        };
        foreach (var form in forms) {
            form.FormClosed += onFormClosed;
        }

        //to show all the forms on start
        //can be included in the previous foreach
        foreach (var form in forms) {
            form.Show();
        }

        //to show only the first form on start
        //forms[0].Show();
    }
}
```

Then, your `Program` class looks like this:

```
static class Program {
    [STAThread]
    static void Main() {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new MyApplicationContext());
    }
}
```

The application closing logic can obviously be customized - are any forms still open, or only one of these three types, or only the first three instances (that would require holding a reference to the first three instances, possibly in a `List<Form>`).

Re: global event for each form creation -- [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8774/Application-Event-Handler-for-WinForms) looks promising.

A similar example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13407161/111794).

Comment: The accepted answer is wrong.  It causes form1 to be a lead form.  This allows each form to be the application until all are removed.  The Race-Condition spoke of will likely never happen, put a lock-object around the remove statement if you absolutely have to worry about it.

Comment: Because the forms are all created on the same thread, there is no race condition.  UI event processing happens sequentially on the UI thread.

Answer (score -1):

also you can use 3 Tabs whit one form Instead of 3 forms

Answer (score -1):

I found my solution by slightly modifying Zev Spitz's answer.

Note: This version only starts the first form specified in the Forms list.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class MyApplicationContext : ApplicationContext
{
    public List<Form> Forms = new List<Form>() {
        new Form1()
    };

    private List<Form> FormCollectionToList(FormCollection fc)
    {
        List<Form> ff = new List<Form>();
        foreach (Form f in fc)
        {
            ff.Add(f);
        }
        return ff;
    }

    private void onFormClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Forms = FormCollectionToList(Application.OpenForms);
        if (Forms.Count == 0)
        {
            ExitThread();
        }
        foreach (var form in Forms)
        {
            form.FormClosed -= onFormClosed;
            form.FormClosed += onFormClosed;
        }
    }

    public MyApplicationContext()
    {
        if (Forms.Count == 0)
        {
            Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
        }
        Forms[0].FormClosed += onFormClosed;
        Forms[0].Show();
    }
}
```

And this version starts all of them.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class MyApplicationContext : ApplicationContext
{
    public List<Form> Forms = new List<Form>() {
        new Form1()
    };

    private List<Form> FormCollectionToList(FormCollection fc)
    {
        List<Form> ff = new List<Form>();
        foreach (Form f in fc)
        {
            ff.Add(f);
        }
        return ff;
    }

    private void onFormClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Forms = FormCollectionToList(Application.OpenForms);
        if (Forms.Count == 0)
        {
            ExitThread();
        }
        foreach (var form in Forms)
        {
            form.FormClosed -= onFormClosed;
            form.FormClosed += onFormClosed;
        }
    }

    public MyApplicationContext()
    {
        if (Forms.Count == 0)
        {
            Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
        }
        foreach (var form in Forms)
        {
            form.FormClosed += onFormClosed;
            form.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `FormsCollectionToList` function. You can write `var openForms = Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>().ToList();`.

Comment: Also, what is the point in checking `Forms.Count` in the constructor? When will it ever be 0?

Comment: Your use of `Application.OpenForms` suggests it is possible to get rid of the private `List<Form>` field. See my updated answer.

Comment: Why do you need to unregister and reregister the `onFormClosed` event handler for **all** the open forms each time **any** form is closed?

Comment: Unless you are concerned with new forms that will be created outside of `MyApplicationContext`? If that is the case then that should be the primary focus of your answer. -1.

Comment: Also, I do need the FormsCollectionToList function.  The FormCollection class does not have a Cast function.

Comment: Anything that implements `IEnumerable` can use the `.Cast` extension method. Add `using System.Linq;` to the top of your code file.