# How to Display Splashscreen and login form at same time using c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to show Splash screen and login form at same time when run my application.

```
static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        SplashImageForm f = new SplashImageForm();
        f.Show();

        Application.Run(f);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
```

Comment: can i get any sample ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13406077/display-multiple-forms-when-c-sharp-application-starts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show your splashscreen from within your form1 and also set the splashscreens its parent to the form1. Because I assume this need to be closed after a certain amount of time. This will also cover the fact that if you close your form1, the splashscreen will also close because of the parent-child relationship.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var f = new SplashImageForm ();
    f.Show( this );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Login Form:

```
    public partial class LoginForm : Form
{


    private void buttonLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //check username password
        if(texboxUser == "user" && texboxPassword == "password")
        {
            DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            Close();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Wrong user pass");
        }
    }
}
```

In Splash form:

```
private void Splash_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoginForm loginF = new LoginForm();

        loginF.ShowDialog();

        if (loginF.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            loginF.Close();
        }
    }
```

In Program.cs:

```
static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Splash());

    }
```